# jquery mobile horizontal controllgroup not displaying properly on mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am trying to keep this controlgroup to stay in a line. When i am viewing this on a mobile device or at my browsers smallest width i get the following image. How can i align them and if a radio is too big have it move to the next line.

[image: jqm offcenter iamge]

```
<form id="myResourcesResourceTypes">
                    <div class="ui-field-contain">
                    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true" >
                        <legend>Resources:</legend>
                        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-h-2" id="radio-choice-h-2a" value="games" checked="checked">
                        <label for="radio-choice-h-2a">Games</label>
                        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-h-2" id="radio-choice-h-2b" value="teams">
                        <label for="radio-choice-h-2b">Teams</label>
                        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-h-2" id="radio-choice-h-2c" value="league">
                        <label for="radio-choice-h-2c">Leagues</label>
                        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-h-2" id="radio-choice-h-2d" value="tournaments">
                        <label for="radio-choice-h-2d">Tournaments</label>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: You should provide your css.

Comment: I am using the default jquery mobile css. Everything i have tried to fix this issue does not work so i just removed it. This seems to be default behavior.

Comment: I tried with *Firefox 39.0*, *jquery-1.11.3* and *jquery.mobile-1.4.5*. The provided html sample works fine on my end: http://i.stack.imgur.com/w77uc.png Either an issue in other browsers, other versions of jQuery or another part of the html that is not shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when i copied the examples from the jquerymobile website they had   in the clipboard when it was copied. I removed all the spacing...